# OpenCV android function use

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, opencv

i have configured opencv 2.4.8 for android with my eclipse . its working fine i have implemented a test example to check it opens opencv loader using folowing code

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
```

then i load a image and converts it to gray scale it successfully converts the image.

Now i want to use more functions of opencv on image like image filtering etc. for kindly suggest me to start doing that and how to use C++ functions in java eclipse android. kindly suggest me any tutorial for that or any example so that i can proceed

Answer (score 2):

You could try the OpenCV examples for android

http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html

Or a basic test from the official website

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android

But I used the examples(in the samples folder in the sdk) instead when I was learning how to use OpenCv in Android

Answer (score 0):

One option that you have is to check the [C++ Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html), and then check this repository where I did some of those [tutorials in Android Java](https://github.com/ruimarques/OpenCV-Imgproc).

More tutorials will be added, if you want a specific one let me know.